# $H^s(\mathbb T)$ is a Banach algebra for $s>1/2$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, banach-algebras

I have not managed to find a reference for the following fact:

*$H^s(\mathbb T)$ is a Banach algebra for $s>1/2$.*

In particular, I need reference for the following inequality:
$$
\|uv\|_{H^s} \,\le\,  c\,\|u\|_{H^s}\|v\|_{H^s},
$$
for all $u,v\in H^s(\mathbb T)$, whenever $s>1/2$, and $c$ is a positive constant not depending on $u,v$.

It is very often assumed to hold, as an obvious fact, and no reference is provided.

Any known reference or proof?

Comment: A complete answer appears in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821818/for-which-s-in-mathbb-r-hs-mathbb-t-is-a-banach-algebra

Answer (score 4):

This follows from two facts:

- $(H^s \cap L^\infty) (\mathbb{T})$ is a Banach algebra (see for example in the framework of fractional spaces $W^{s, p}$ ($W^{s, 2} = H^s$) Bourgain, Brezis, Mironescu, *Lifting in Sobolev spaces*, 2000),
- if $s > \frac{1}{2}$, then $H^{s} (\mathbb{T}) \subset L^\infty (\mathbb{T})$: if $u \in H^s (\mathbb{T})$ and $t \in \mathbb{T}$, then 
  $$\vert u (t) \vert \le \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \vert c_k (u)\vert
  \le \Big(\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}  \frac{1}{(k^2 + 1)^s}\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\Big(\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}  \lvert c_k (u) \vert^2 (k^2 + 1)^s\Big)^\frac{1}{2}
  = C \Vert u \Vert_{H^s},$$
  where $c_k (u)$ is the $k$-th Fourier coefficient of the function $u$.
  In general $W^{s, p} (M)$ is continuously embedded into $L^\infty (M)$ if $sp > \dim M$ (see for example Adams, *Sobolev spaces*, Academic Press, 1975, theorem 7.57).

More generally $W^{s, p} (M)$ is a Banach algebra if $sp > \dim M$.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your last assertion? Does one have that $W^{s,p}(M)\hookrightarrow L^\infty(M)$ if $sp>{\rm dim } M$?

Comment: Adams, _Sobolev spaces_, Academic Press, 1975, theorem 7.57

Comment: But 7.57 is an imbedding result for Sobolev spaces on domains of $\mathbb R^n$! How does this implies the claimed property? 

I have checked a bit in the literature: It seems that Thm. 3.5 in *Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds* by E. Hebey settles my question.

Comment: This holds for a compact manifold: by Adams and local charts, the result holds on a neighbourhood of any point, and the manifold can be covered by finitely many such neighbourhoods. This should also work for manifolds with some “bounded geometry”.